# Generic Proxy Class

Tags: c#, generics, proxy

This may not the worded quite right but here goes anyway.

If I have the following statements;

```
DocumentMerger<EmailMerge> mailMerge = new DocumentMerger<EmailMerge>();
List<MailMessage> mailMessages = mailMerge.Process();

DocumentMerger<SmsMerge> mailMerge = new DocumentMerger<SmsMerge>();
List<SmsMessage> smsMessages = mailMerge.Process();
```

How can I create a generic class that takes a type as its generic such as `EmailMerge` and returns either a list of MailMessage or SmsMessage objects?

I have a class called DocumentMerger which creates my object EmailMerge or SmsMerge.

I now need both of them to expose a Process method which returns its own unique list of objects such as `List<MaileMessage>` or `List<SmsMessage>`

I suspect proxies might be the go here but can't work out the code.

Please re-title this question if you think it's not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

An interface could solve your problem..

```
public interface IDocumentMerger
{
}

public interface IOutputType
{
}

public class MailMessage : IOutputType
{
}

public class EmailMerge : IDocumentMerger
{
}

public class SmsMerge : IDocumentMerger
{
}

public class DocumentMerger<T> where T : IDocumentMerger
{
  public List<IOutputType> Process()
  { 
      IOutputType result = null;

      if (typeof(T) == EmailMerge)
      {
          result = new MailMessage();
      }

      // etc..
      // do stuff..

      return result;
  }
}
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
var documentMerger = new DocumentMerger<EmailMerge>();

var emailMerge = documentMerger.Process();
```

emailMerge is of type `List<MailMessage>`...

I hope I understood your question correctly.. Code is untested, but should be correct.. Or really close to it :)

Ian

edit -- looks like I misread your requirements.. it's an easy fix though, see edit.

Comment: You can extend this solution to have a Factory Pattern in place, by simply adding another Facotry class. This could avoid a few switch cases and conditions in your calling class. 

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx

Comment: I'm not really understanding what IOutputType is because I get a conversion error at result = new MailMessage();  Sorry, but am I missing something here?

Comment: griegs -MailMessage should implement the IOutputType interface.